# Bug when running code snippet

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I discovered a bug in the code editor. The following code has two videos, which should automatically play if the video is in the viewport and pause if the video is not in the viewport anymore.

This works if you edit the question, press on "edit the above snippet" and then run the code from there. But it does not work if you press on the button "Run code snippet" in the question.

```js
// Limitation: Does not work if the element is
// out of view because it is too far right or left
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

setInterval(function() {
    $('video').each(function(){
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
            $(this)[0].play();
        } else {
            $(this)[0].pause();
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

```css
#right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2000px;
}
#video1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 1000px;
}
#video2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 2000px;
}

body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info"></div>

<div id="down">
  scroll down please...
</div>

<video id="video1" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video id="video2" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: What's your browser and do you have any browser add-ons? This is working fine for me on Chrome for MacOS and Android.

Comment: I am using Chrome 86.0.4240.198 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit) with many extensions, windows 10.

Comment: I tested it again in inspector mode with no extensions and it still does not work.

Comment: works fine for me using FF on windows

Comment: I guess this is a [tag:status-norepro]... It's working fine for me.

Comment: Edge on Windows 10 - works fine for me.  Both videos play.  You admit you have "many extensions".  So try removing all of them and see if it works for you.

Comment: I'm on Chrome Latest/ Win 10 and works fine for. Both play and stop according to your description and expectation. Also checked when on full page.

Comment: @rene "bug" is that it's not auto playing.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard it is auto-playing for me?

Comment: "You admit you have "many extensions". So try removing all of them and see if it works for you"
I already wrote that I did that but it still fails.

Comment: @rene very weird, for me it's not auto playing, same OS/browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug on Stack Exchange's side.

If you open up the dev console, you'll see a clear error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

A possible fix can be found on Stack Overflow: [How to handle "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." on Desktop with Chrome 66?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use).

Comment: You are correct! If I add `muted="muted"` to the video tags, then it works!

Comment: `muted` alone is enough btw. You dont have to use `muted="muted"`

Comment: @Black cheers, consider adding this as comment to the SO answer as well.